# How to get method signature

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

My unversity's website has a search form to access the list of courses. You select a bunch of criteria (faculty, term, etc) and then you press "Get Course Sections" and it displays all the courses that match the criteria given. I want to get all the courses, so I want to figure out how to directly call that button with my own parameters. My knowledge of HTML and javascript is quite minimal, but I think I'm making some progress. Here's the relevant (I think) source:

```
<form action="/pban1/bwskfcls.P_GetCrse" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkSubmit()">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="term_in" value="201209">
<input type="hidden" name="sel_subj" value="dummy">
<input type="hidden" name="sel_day" value="dummy">
<input type="hidden" name="sel_schd" value="dummy">
<input type="hidden" name="sel_insm" value="dummy">
<input type="hidden" name="sel_camp" value="dummy">
<input type="hidden" name="sel_levl" value="dummy">
<input type="hidden" name="sel_sess" value="dummy">
<input type="hidden" name="sel_instr" value="dummy">
<input type="hidden" name="sel_ptrm" value="dummy">
<input type="hidden" name="sel_attr" value="dummy">
<table class="dataentrytable" summary="Table is used to present the course search criteria" .. </table>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Get Course Sections">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

The way I understand it (I very easily could be wrong), when you press the button it calls the function checkSubmit() (which has trivial code) then submits a "POST" request to "/pban1/bwskfcls.P_GetCrse". Somehow it also passes some parameters to that URL (is it javascript? PHP? no clue).

If I try to place the url called in the address bar `https://banweb.mcgill.ca/pban1/bwskfcls.P_GetCrse` it opens a page with the following error:

```
mod_plsql: /pban1/bwskfcls.P_GetCrse HTTP-404 bwskfcls.P_GetCrse: MANY PROCEDURES MATCH NAME, BUT NONE MATCHES SIGNATURE (parameter names)
```

So I'm understanding that I'm not passing the right parameters. Which parameters must I pass, and how do I do it?

If any other source is required I'd be happy to post it. Any input or clarification is appreciated, I've gotten to this point only through trial and error and lots of googling unknown terms.

**EDIT:** 
Here's the code for checksubmit()

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- Hide JavaScript from older browsers 
var submitcount=0;
function checkSubmit() {
if (submitcount == 0)
   {
   submitcount++;
   return true;
   }
else
   {
alert("Your changes have already been submitted.");
   return false;
   }
}
//  End script hiding -->
</script>
```

Comment: though it may look trivial, can you post the code for `checkSubmit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks for the answers, they were of some help, but I had to do some more digging to figure out the exact signature needed.

What I did was open the developer tools in Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+I), and switched to the network tab. There I was able to monitor all network activity. I then pressed the "Get Course Sections" button. Lo and behold, I saw the POST request pop up!

I clicked on it and found all the parameters being passed in the request under the header "form data". I rewrote them in the url?p1:v1&p2:v2... format, and opened the completed URL in my browser. Success! No CURL necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When a `form` is submitted, all the fields in the form are submitted to the server. In your form you have a bunch of hidden fields, and all of these hidden fields are passed as parameters to the server in a POST request.

Something like

```
/pban1/bwskfcls.P_GetCrse?term_in=201209&sel_subj=dummy...
```

The server them (looks like) calls a stored procedure with the parameters (presumably after stripping off the parameters that have `dummy` as the value).

The error says

> MANY PROCEDURES MATCH NAME, BUT NONE MATCHES SIGNATURE (parameter
>   names)

So looks like there are procedures already defined for some sets of parameters but not for all. So there may be a stored procedure to do the search with `faculty` and `term` as input but none just for `faculty`.

Answer (score 0):

The form in your example passes all the parameters given in the `<input type="hidden" ../>` fields to the script. In your example code, there is no JavaScript involved (but `CheckSubmit()`), but I assume, that JavaScript is used to set the values of those input fields.

Your best chance will be to submit all of them and just modifying those matching your search criteria.

To issue a request manually you could use tools like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) from a linux/unix console.

Comment: Is that how it usually works, input elements of type "hidden" are the ones passed as parameters with the POST request?

Comment: @Lanaru All `<input>` fields, that are enclosed by the `<form>` tag are passed as parameters. `<input type="hidden" ../>` are just those, that you wont see in the UI (hence they are hidden). There could also be others like `<input type="text" ../>` or `<textarea></textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fake the call to the server, you will need to open page with a POST call. You cannot do this from the browser. You can use server side code or a CURL request like

```
CURL -X POST -d 'term_in=201209&sel_subj=dummy&sel_day=dummy&sel_schd=dummy......' https://banweb.mcgill.ca/pban1/bwskfcls.P_GetCrse
```

Replace dummy with the correct values and replace the ... with the rest of the values.
That is assuming the site isn't checking for cookies. If that is the case you will have to add the cookies from your browser to the CURL call. Check CURL documentation on how to do that.

You can also do it in server code that has a curl library.